# Receive messages from socket python server

Tags: java, python, sockets, input

I tried to read message on socket with bufferreader

My client:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.4", 12345);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

My python server:

```py
(client, (address, _)) = server.accept()  # Accept to new clients (Accept to new command from the phone)
client.send("Hello from server")
```

But when I send a message from the server to the client, the code gets stack in the last line `System.out.println(in.readLine());` like he is waiting for something.

And whan I turn off the server, I get an error.

**How can I read the input from my server with Java?**

Comment: `readLine` is waiting for a new line character. Is a newline being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @James comment states, seems like you are waiting for a carriage return or line feed (complete line) that is not being sent by the server.

That leads to your code being waiting forever until **`\n`**, **`\r`** or **`\r\n`** are received.

> [**`readLine()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is **considered to be terminated** by any
> one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage
> return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So your `in.readline()` never considers the line to be terminated, and keeps *[hopefully](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/09/e5/af/09e5af7b53ecb7480e6f38450a89be24.jpg)* waiting for it to end. In order to avoid this, instead of sending:

```
   client.send("Hello from server")
```

Send

```
   client.send("Hello from server\n")
```

Or even better, check if that Python library has something similar to a `sendLine()` method.

---

In order to loop receiving server's messages, something like this could work:

```
while (socket.isConnected()) 
{
  String inputLine;
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: It still does not print anything and seems to be waiting for something

Comment: the maybe the socket is not connected at all? updating

Comment: this would avoid any wait if the socket is not connected. Are you sure the server is sending anything?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because, when I tried to read the messages with ```DataInputStream``` and I tried to read as int, I got 84 (It means that I got the message from the server)

Comment: But I don't know what is going to work for me, because ```DataInputStream``` can't sow me string

Comment: show***********

Comment: Check out my edit in 20 sec

Comment: Send this instead:             client.send("Hello from server \n")

Comment: ```java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String``` I got an error

Comment: I can't check if int is null

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You have no idea how many nights I sat on it

Comment: now you can go to sleep in peace mate : )

Comment: Thank you! There are no words in my mouth to thank you

Comment: 1000 € in my bank account would be enough : ) Just kidding, good luck in life mate

Comment: Thank you mate. Have a good day